# Counts no longer shown in filter list view

Tags: discussion, filtering

If I click `edit` next to `Favorite Tags` on the front page, then `advanced tag subscriptions »`, I get to a screen with my list of filters in the top right and the newest 50 questions in whatever tag I had selected last. It used to be that the list of filters would show the number that were new since the last time I visited the tag; now there are no numbers.

The HTML of each filter element looks like this:

```
<li class="current">
    <div class="filter-name">
        <a href="/filters/47151/git" title="git">git</a>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-unread-count" id="filter-unread-47151"></div>
</li>
```

As you can see, there is a div for the count, but no count.

Is this by design? (BTW, I remember before this stopped working completely, I would similarly see a filter list with no counts if I was on one filter, went to another one, and then hit the back button.)